# What tables is needed to store OAuth server data (not client)

Tags: php, mysql, oauth

I'm currently learning OAuth. I've been tinkering with this [OAuth library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/), specifically, the PHP version.

It's barebone but enough to get me grasp the basic idea. Now, my learning move on to storing the data into database. Several things that *I think* I already know:

- I need to create table that store application specific consumer key and consumer secret
- I need to create table that store user access token key and secret specific to application (along date generated so that next time, when I need to implement token expiration, I can use it)

Now, enter the questions:

- do I need another table? or these two are enough?

Comment: If you want it to "just work", I suggest the oauth-php library. It has several storage modules (a few DBs and sessions). The MySQL module includes a .sql file with the requisite tables.

Comment: I don't want to "just work" I want to do it myself, so that I know the internal processes. I'm in the learning phase. If I use an already built product and someday it failed, I think it will be hard to debug if I don't know how it work

Answer (score 2):

You need one table to handle application keys. There will be a public/private token for every application that's authorized to handle your server data.

```
AppID | Public Token | Private Token | Callback URL | Additional App Data
------+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------
    1 | aaaaaaaaaaaa | bbbbbbbbbbbbb | http:///     | Test App #1
    2 | cccccccccccc | ddddddddddddd | http:///     | Test App #2
```

You should already have customer data table. So you will need a table that links the customer token/application token to a customer id.

```
App ID | Customer ID | Public Token | Private Token
-------+-------------+--------------+--------------
     1 |           1 | zzzzzzzzzzzz | yyyyyyyyyyyy 
     2 |           1 | xxxxxxxxxxxx | wwwwwwwwwwww
```

You will also need to track nonce and timestamp information to avoid replay attacks.

Comment: how should I track nonce and timestamp? yet another table?

Comment: Since nonce and timestamp checking is mainly for shorter periods of time, you can probably keep those in memory.